# Populate values in Zend Form multi-select option

Tags: php, zend-framework

So my form is

```
class Form_Group_ShareGroup extends Form_Abstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttrib('class', 'shareForm');

        //Row 1
        $this->addElement('select', 'groups', array(
            'decorators' => $this->getElementDecorators(),
            'label' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Groups_Colon'),
            'style' => 'width:320px;',
            'multiple' => true,
            'data-help' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Please_Select_Groups_Share')
        ));

        $this->addElement('select', 'users', array(
            'decorators' => $this->getElementDecorators(),
            'label' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Users_Colon'),
            'style' => 'width:320px;',
            'multiple' => true,
            'data-help' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Select_Users_To_Share_Group_With')
        ));


        //Row 2
        $this->addElement('button', 'share', array(
            'decorators' => $this->buttonDecorators,
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'type'     => 'submit',
            'label'    => 'Share',
            'class'    => 'btn primary'
        ));
    }
}
```

and I want to populate some user data into "users" element.
example could be :

```
array('10000105' => 'aamaddy1 m aamaddy1','10000106' => 'aamaddy2 m aamaddy2' )
```

How can I achieve this ?

I have use populate method but it didnt worked out.

to view the form I am using :

```
$usersGroup = new Form_Group_ShareGroup();
$this->view->usersGroup = $usersGroup;
```

Please help ! 
Thanks for reading .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$data = array('10000105' => 'aamaddy1 m aamaddy1','10000106' => 'aamaddy2 m aamaddy2' );
$usersGroup = new Form_Group_ShareGroup();
$usersGroup->getElement('users')->setMultiOptions($data);
```